# Key length issue: AES encryption on phpseclib and decryption on PyCrypto

Tags: php, python, aes, pycrypto, phpseclib

I am working on a data intensive project where I have been using PHP for fetching data and encrypting it using phpseclib. A chunk of the data has been encrypted in AES with the ECB mode -- however the key length is only 10. I am able to decrypt the data successfully.

However, I need to use Python in the later stages of the project and consequently need to decrypt my data using it. I tried employing PyCrypto but it tells me the key length must be 16, 24 or 32 bytes long, which is not the case. According to the phpseclib documentation the "keys are null-padded to the closest valid size", but I'm not sure how to implement that in Python. Simply extending the length of the string with 6 spaces is not working.

What should I do?

Comment: *According to the phpseclib documentation the "keys are null-padded to the closest valid size"* > Wow.

Comment: @Duncan Jones - sounds like you're being critical of phpseclib? What would you propose as an alternative? If you want to make use of PBKDF2 use setPassword(). setKey() is intended for stuff like phpseclib's SSH2 implementation and that does not use PBKDF2. Keys are derived in that through diffie-hellman key exchange. If you do PBKDF2 on a key derived through that your implementation won't be inter operable with any other SSH implementation. As for null-padding vs. throwing an error for setKey().. that behavior is consistent with PHP's API tbh. Silently adjust data instead of throwing errors.

Comment: @neubert "*that behavior is consistent with PHP's API tbh*" > Ok, that makes some sense then. Still, I worry how many PHP applications have a minor coding error that leads to short/weak keys being used with no-one the wiser!

Comment: The phpseclib author has chimmed in on this: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/135 Basically, according to him, not only is phpseclib's way of doing things consistent with PHP, as per neubert, but it's also consistent with other crypto libs like mcrypt and OpenSSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend you adjust your PHP code to use (at least) a sixteen byte key, otherwise your crypto system is considerably weaker than it might otherwise be.

I would also recommend you switch to CBC-mode, as ECB-mode may reveal patterns in your input data. Ensure you use a random IV each time you encrypt and store this with the ciphertext.

Finally, to address your original question:

> According to the phpseclib documentation the "keys are null-padded to the closest valid size", but I'm not sure how to implement that in Python. Simply extending the length of the string with 6 spaces is not working.

The space character `0x20` is not the same as the null character `0x00`.

Comment: Two down-votes on this answer - I'd appreciate if anyone can suggest where I've made a mistake?